# Не работает SeekBar после сворачивания приложения

Tags: android, аудио, mediaplayer

Я сделал аудио плеер. Все работает, но когда я сворачиваю программу и открываю заново, прогресс бар уже не работает. Как решить проблему?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    TextView tb_title;

    int  pos  = 0;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final String[] listContent = { "0000", "0001",  };
    private final int[] resID = { R.raw.a0001, R.raw.a0000,  };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        // Initializing variables
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);



            }
        });



    }


    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            mp.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }


    public void play (View view) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop (View view) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
// Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);




        mp.start();


        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mSeekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());


        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


        });



        startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }


    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mp.pause();

            mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: И плейлист включает музыку поверх того что уже было

Comment: Многовато кода, но, думаю, вам надо просто MediaPlayer синглтоном сделать.